# Using a .raw file to create a BOOTCAMP partition

Tags: bootcamp, partition

How would one go about using a *.raw* (hard drive image from a .vdi) file containing an installation of Windows 10 in the creation of a BOOTCAMP partition (for Windows 10), on the latest version of OS X?

Comment: To install Windows on a Mac, one normally uses the Boot Camp Assistant to create the BOOTCAMP partition, download the Boot Camp Support Software and then start the Windows installation. Where did the _.raw_ file come from, how was it created and what does it contain?

Comment: @user3439894 - the .raw file was created from a .vdi file, which contains the information for a virtual hard disk. The goal would be to use it to actually boot Windows, instead of just doing so inside of a VM. (It has windows 10 installed, and a few other applications.)

Comment: Bootcamp is not a VM

Comment: @patrix I understand that. The point is to take the VM, a .vdi file that can be / has been converted into a .raw file, and turn it into a bootcamp partition. So that it can be used _not_ as a VM, and instead be dual booted to.